# How can I use flip view with multiple item and flip by other button in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am tried to change item by other button in flip view so I used to  PointerWheelChanged with True value and also IsHitTestVisible="False". But I failed tp connect with Button, Please help me to got right.

Comment: It's not clear about what you want to get. Please share more details about the expected behavior you want to get. Are you trying to disable the scroll function of the flipview?

Comment: @Roy Li - MSFT        Yes, I wanted to disable scroll function and then scroll with Button that added by me.

Comment: It looks like you've successfully disabled the scroll function of the mouse wheel, right? So now your question is that you want to know how to create a custom button and control the scrolling function of the flip view, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xaml`

```
  <FlipView x:Name="flipView1" Width="1000" Height="400" 
                                    BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Blue" Loaded="flipView1_Loaded"  >
                           
                            <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  PointerWheelChanged="VirtualizingStackPanel_PointerWheelChanged"></VirtualizingStackPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                           

                        </FlipView>
```

<-- Now Add two button for mutual control -->

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="previous" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBlock Text="Previous" FontSize="13" Foreground="White" Margin="12,0,0,5"/>
                <StackPanel Background="White" Width="35" Margin="0,0,75,0">
                    <Button x:Name="btnPrevious"  Foreground="Black" Width="35" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="btnPrevious_Click">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Back" Width="20" />
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
              </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="next" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
                <TextBlock Text="Next" FontSize="13" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,15,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                <StackPanel Background="White" Width="35"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,0">
                    <Button x:Name="btnNext"  Foreground="Black" Width="40" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="btnNext_Click" >
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Forward" Width="Auto"  />
                           
                        </Button>
                </StackPanel>
```

Code -Behind :

```
  private void VirtualizingStackPanel_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

    }


    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = flipView1.SelectedIndex;
        if (index == (flipView1.Items.Count - 2))
        {
            next.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        index = index + 1;
        if (index < flipView1.Items.Count)
        {
            flipView1.SelectedIndex = index;
            previous.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = flipView1.SelectedIndex;
        if (index == 1)
        {
            previous.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        index = index - 1;
        if (index < flipView1.Items.Count && index >= 0)
        {
            flipView1.SelectedIndex = index;
            next.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void flipView1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(flipView1, 0);
        for (int i = grid.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (grid.Children[i] is Button)
                grid.Children.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I have done this already. Can you please help me to remove ban from my account ? It's restricted me to ask answer and Its painful for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

If you want to remove the default Button of Flip View, you just need to change its style.

First, you need to create a copy of the default style of the `FlipView`, Go to the **Document Outline** window in Visual Studio, find the `FlipView` control. Right-click on the `FlipView` choose **Edit Template**->**Edit a Copy**.  Then the Visual Studio will automatically create a default style of the `FlipView`.  Then what you need is to remove the default buttons on the bottom of the style.

Here is the style that you could refer to:

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FlipViewStyle1" TargetType="FlipView">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel AreScrollSnapPointsRegular="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlipView">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalNextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Root" Background="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackground}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrush}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForegroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForeground}" FontSize="12" Glyph="&#xE0E3;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalPreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Root" Background="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackground}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrush}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForegroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForeground}" FontSize="12" Glyph="&#xE0E2;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalNextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Root" Background="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackground}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrush}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForegroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForeground}" FontSize="12" Glyph="&#xE0E5;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalPreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Root" Background="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackground}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrush}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForegroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource FlipViewNextPreviousArrowForeground}" FontSize="12" Glyph="&#xE0E4;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollingHost" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsTabStop="False" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <!--<Button x:Name="PreviousButtonHorizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalPreviousTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20"/>
                        <Button x:Name="NextButtonHorizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="36" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalNextTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20"/>
                        <Button x:Name="PreviousButtonVertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource VerticalPreviousTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36"/>
                        <Button x:Name="NextButtonVertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource VerticalNextTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="36"/>-->
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

And use it for the `FlipView`

```
<FlipView Style="{StaticResource FlipViewStyle1}" x:Name="flipView1">
```

You could get more information about styles here: [Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-styles)

---

To control the scrolling function of the flip view, you just need to change the **FlipView.SelectedIndex property** in the code behind with your custom button.

I've made a very simple demo to show how it works. I created a data class that only contains an image. And should them in a `flipview` using data-binding. I disabled the mouse wheel scrolling function by handling the `PointerWheelChanged` event. Then I added two buttons to scroll the `flipview` by changing the **FlipView.SelectedIndex property**

**Xaml:**

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Next" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Previous" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <FlipView x:Name="flipView1">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid PointerWheelChanged="flipView1_PointerWheelChanged">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageContent}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

**Code-behind:**

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
public List source { get; set; }
public MainPage()
{
this.InitializeComponent();

```
        source = new List<ImageData>();
        source.Add(new ImageData { ImageContent = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/london.png"))});
        source.Add(new ImageData { ImageContent = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/paris.png")) });
        source.Add(new ImageData { ImageContent = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/seattle.png")) });
        source.Add(new ImageData { ImageContent = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/vancouver.png")) });
        flipView1.ItemsSource = source;
    }

    private void flipView1_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        if (btn.Content.Equals("Next"))
        {
            //go to next item. check if it is the last item
            if (flipView1.SelectedIndex< source.Count-1) 
            {
                flipView1.SelectedIndex = flipView1.SelectedIndex + 1;
            }
            
        }
        else 
        {
            //go back to pervious item. Check if it is the first item
            if (flipView1.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                flipView1.SelectedIndex = flipView1.SelectedIndex - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ImageData 
{
    public BitmapImage ImageContent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I am also want to remove Flip View default Button then Which step I will have to follow ?  and Please help me to know about What is  the best resource to learn C# and XAML with UWP ?

Comment: @ShashankSingh I've updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank you so much @Roy Li - MSFT